# ASP.Net multiple session same browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I come to some critical problem. Web site have 2 option to login.
1. Web User for simple way of login where user type uid/pwd 
2. Encrypted URL actually this kind of url open by some application so directly user of that application able to see web page after login details.

Now come to problem.
user open IE and login in website. also have install that app and open url same url open in IE as different tab and that also login.

now session variable  created by first tab was override by second tab.
now if we do any activity in first tab it's treat as second tab activity because 
session variable value from first tab was override value.

I have use Form Authentication for login.

I don't want to use cookieless sessions.

Comment: There is no solution. Cookies are shared between tabs, period (well, unless you consider incognito tabs). You'll have to go cookieless or change your approach altogether.

Comment: The session is stored inside a cookie and linked to authentication. So, when you login, you erase the preceding session. This is a feature, not a bug: if you open another tab you are already logged in. From the top of my mind, either you ask the users to open multiple browsers (Chrome and Firefox or Edge or Safari), each one with a separate cookie and therefore session, or you have to completely re-implement the session provider and the authentication system. The first solution can be heavy for the users, the second is really, really difficult to put in place.